# Force Trailing Zeroes in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

I copied code from stackoverflow using InputFilter to force the edit text to have 3 digits before the "." and 2 digits after (2 decimal places). However, I want the system to display 15.00 if user only enters 15?

So scenario I want is.. edit text must have 2 decimal places maximum.. e.g. 12.56 but if user only enters 15 then edit text field adds 2 zeros in the end so 15 -> 15.00

How do i do this in the addTextChangedListener?

Code from stackoverflow regarding inputfilter

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

Pattern mPattern;

public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
    mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    String s = Html.toHtml(dest).replaceAll("\\<.*?>","").replaceAll("\n","");
    Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(dest);
    if (!matcher.matches())
        return "";
    try {
        if(Double.parseDouble(s)<9999.99 && s.contains(".")) {
            return null;
        }else if ((Double.parseDouble(s)<1000 && !s.contains("."))||source.equals(".")) {
            return null;
        }else {
            return "";
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
    /// in main activity
   numberReceivedEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(3, 2)}); 
   numberReceivedEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please share the code snippet?

Comment: just posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
numberReceivedEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(numberReceivedEditText)});

numberReceivedEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (i2 == 0) return;
            int cursorLocation = numberReceivedEditText.getSelectionStart();
            String data = numberReceivedEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                if (!data.contains(".")) {
                    data = data + ".";
                }

                try {
                    data = String.format(Locale.JAPANESE, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(data));
                    numberReceivedEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    numberReceivedEditText.setText(data);
                    numberReceivedEditText.setSelection(cursorLocation < data.length() ? cursorLocation : cursorLocation - 1, cursorLocation);
                    numberReceivedEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });

class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

TextView tvNumber;

public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(TextView tvNumber) {
    this.tvNumber = tvNumber;
}

public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    try {
        if (Double.parseDouble(tvNumber.getText().toString()) > 1000) {
            String[] splitValue = tvNumber.getText().toString().split("\\.");
            return splitValue[0].substring(0,3) + "." + splitValue[1];
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return source;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: it works if i enter just one number.. like 2 becomes 2.00. but i also want to enter larger numbers.. also if the user wants to enter with 2 decimals i cannot anymore with your code. so 2.45, 12.78, 65.45 should be allowed. but when the user enters just 15 the result should be 15.00 to force the 2 decimals to be zero

Comment: Hi @ZandroZulueta, I know I'm late, have you changed the filter definition?

Comment: hi no its still an open issue. i just decided to make a check externally instead before saving the data to the database to see if user inputted 2 d.p. or not